# How to show Google's user and password saver message for future autofill logins in my app?

Tags: android

I have 2 EditText, one with Username and another with Password.

I want to save both in my googgle passwords for autofill in the future logins in the app.

How can achieve this?

[image]

Thank you!

EDIT:

I Tried this.

```
val options: CredentialsOptions = CredentialsOptions.Builder().forceEnableSaveDialog().build()
        val mCredentialsClient = Credentials.getClient(this, options)
        var credential = Credential.Builder(login_user_id.text.toString()).setPassword(login_user_password.text.toString()).build()
        mCredentialsClient.save(credential).addOnCompleteListener{
            Toast.makeText(this,"GUARDADO BRO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
```

After i do de Login i execute that code. It shows the toast, but i want the Google Smartlock message to show up but it doesnt happen.

//EDIT2: Ok, the code from Above is for Google Smart Lock and its not what im looking for. I Want to see that native username with saved password box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after an entire day of research i found the problem.

In the XML you have to set the inputType to the correct way. I already had that.

```
android:inputType="textPassword" --> For passowrd

android:inputType="textEmailAddress" --> for mail
```

And then, when you do the succesfull login you MUST to do **finish()** so in the background android do the magic and ask you to save the data in your google passwords or samsung pass or whatever.